# Check enabled/disabled status of a draggable element in jQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have some elements which are draggable and I'm changing their status like this:

```
$(obj).draggable("enable");
// and:
$(obj).draggable("disable");
```

How can I check the current state of a draggable object, ie. if it's enabled or disabled in jQueryUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the draggable element is disabled like this:

```
var isDisabled = $(obj).draggable('option', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var status=$(obj).draggable();
```

status will current draggable status of `obj`.